# Multiple while conditions

Tags: c#, while-loop

I want to output a timer in console which goes from 00h00m00s to 23h59m59s.
My code only outputs until 00h00m59s.
Must be the conditions in after the while, but i think it is correct.
Who knows how to solve this ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int uur = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int sec = 0;

        while (uur != 23 && min!=60 && sec!=60)
        {
            if (sec == 60)
            {
                min++;
                sec = 0;
            }
            if (min == 60)
            {
                uur++;
                min = 0;
            }

            string strSec = String.Format("{0:00}", sec);
            string strMin = String.Format("{0:00}", min);
            string strUur = String.Format("{0:00}", uur);

            Console.WriteLine(strUur + "h" + strMin + "m" + strSec + "s");
            sec++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: What's going to happen in the while condition when sec = 60?

Comment: it must stop. just print untill 23h59m59s.

Comment: The first comment is a hint.

Comment: huhmm ... maybe my knowledge is that poor (i know it is).but it must just go on untill 23h59m59s ... i used &&, so nothing on 60sec ?? :) enlighten me pls

Comment: at the first occurrence of 60 seconds, your statement `uur != 23 && min != 60 && sec != 60` will evaluate to false, because sec == 60

Comment: Your while condition means: continue while all criteria are met. When min = 60 the second condition is no longer met so the while loop will end.

Comment: why, i used the AND operator ? he should only evaluate a false when AND 23h AND 59m AND 59 sec

Comment: No, it will evaluate to true when **all** conditions are met. If even one of them doesn't, it will be false.

Comment: @eldje `true && true && false => false`

Comment: @eldje, because you used the AND operator, when `sec == 60`, although your `min` and `uur` is `!= 60` and `23` respectively, your statement becomes `true && true && false`. Now what will that be?

Comment: Huhmmm which conditions should I write then?

Comment: If you want to stick with your approach you could convert the `while` loop to a `do-while` loop. The code would then be `do {...} while (!(uur == 23 && min == 59 && sec == 60))`

Comment: tnx! the difference between "while" and "for" is getting clearer i think !! ;-) i have it working now with "while (( uur+sec+min)!=(23+59+60))"

Answer (score 2):

Use the following condition:

```
while (uur != 23 || min != 59 || sec != 60)
```

You might also want to try this simpler approach:

```
int total_second_in_day = 24*60*60;

for (int second_in_day = 0; second_in_day < total_second_in_day; second_in_day++)
{
    int uur = second_in_day / 3600;
    int min = (second_in_day % 3600) / 60;
    int sec = (second_in_day % 3600) % 60;

    string strSec = String.Format("{0:00}", sec);
    string strMin = String.Format("{0:00}", min);
    string strUur = String.Format("{0:00}", uur);

    Console.WriteLine(strUur + "h" + strMin + "m" + strSec + "s");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is basically about understanding `while` conditions this is how you could achieve printing all times:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0);
        var oneSec = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
        var wakeywakey = new TimeSpan(0,23,59,59);

        while (time <= wakeywakey)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(time);
            time += oneSec;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change the condition to `while (time <= wakywaky)`

Comment: Better use TimeSpan static factory methods (TimeSpan.FromSeconds, FromDays) instead of the ugly constructor. They make code much more readable.